# Slow performance when using classic ASP with ADODB on Window 2012 and IIS, Oracle Database

Tags: windows, oracle, iis, asp-classic, adodb

I have a ASP classic web application running on IIS 6.0 and Windows 2003, it uses Oracle Instant Client 10g and ODBC to fetch data using ADODB.

I have moved this application to IIS 8.0 and Windows 2012, using Oracle Instant Client 12c and ODBC to fetch data using ADODB.

The application works as it should, but the web pages accessing the Database takes longer time than in the previous environment. I have runned the queries in sqlplus with the execution time 10ms, running the same query with ASP the execution time exceeds 100ms. I think that this is what is causing my moved application to take long time to run.

QUESTION:

- How can I trace/debug this issue?
- Is there something in the switch from W2003/IIS6/Oracle Instant Client 10g to W2012/IIS8/Oracle Instant Client 12c that can effect the performance?
- Any other tips?

Comment: Any luck with that? we are having the same problem